# How to remove container box in Wordpress pages?

Tags: pages

I would like some help on removing the container box from all my pages (Theme: Zerif Lite). In the screenshot below, you will see it red-boxed.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Suraj

Edit 1: I think I have resolved this. In the Content Section of the Editor, I found this snippet of code, and made a minor change to it.

```
    article.hentry {
    border: 1px solid #FFF; /* Changed the border color to white*/
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #FFF !important;
    }
```

The border is not visible anymore.

Comment: First show your effort , what have you done ? .. otherwise you don't answers,it's like asking people to do your job

Comment: I think I may have fixed it. I would be grateful if you could provide your input on what I have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set border property to none instead of white.

```
article.hentry {
        border: none; // set this to none for no border
        padding: 1px;
        background-color: #FFF !important;
    }
```